# How to find the median of Males and Females separately from a dataset in R?

Tags: r

From the following data, I want to extract mean for Males and Females separately. How do I achieve this in R??

[image]

Comment: I think this is a question that is a bit broad for the format of this site. This site is all about getting answers to specific coding questions, less about having people implement complete solutions for you. Furthermore, this seems like a very basic question.

Comment: To add to Kris's comment, you should copy text rather than insert images where possible so that, say, somebody would be able to copy/paste your data and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(variable=c(rep('Males', 10), rep('Females', 10)), value=sample(1:1000, 20))
df$variable <- as.factor(df$variable)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(variable) %>% summarise(average = mean(value))
df2
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  variable average
1  Females   566.8
2    Males   575.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `which` to identify the rows for male/female. Here some example data:

```
df <- data.frame(variable=c(rep('Males', 10), rep('Females', 10)), value=sample(1:1000, 20))
```

and then

```
mean(df[which(df$variable=='Males'),]$value)
mean(df[which(df$variable=='Females'),]$value)
```

Also have a look at `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(.~variable, data=df, mean)
```